# Define a custom Observable in Angular2+

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a simple [css animation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-load-animation) library that allows the display of an animation by calling `loadService.animate(boolean);` but sadly it does not function anymore as I have been wrongly using an `EventEmitter` in my service like such:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoadService {
    @Output() animating: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    constructor() {}

    // User calls animate, we emit an event with the new boolean value
    public animate(val: boolean) {
        this.animating.emit(val);
    }

    getValue(): any {
        return this.animating;
    }
}
```

And subscribing to it in my component:

```
// Animation shown when animate == true
animate: boolean;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadService.getValue().subscribe((status: boolean) => {
        // Events caught, we change the boolean to display the animation
        this.animate = status;
    });
    this.handleShape();
}
```

But my subscription never catches anything, so I figured I wanted to **create a custom `Observable`** in order to simply catch when a user calls `animate` and consequently change the value of my boolean.

How may I define a custom observable in Angular2+? And how may I implement it in this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### LoadService

In our service we create a `BehaviorSubject` with default value of `false`:

```
private _animate = BehaviorSubject(false);
get animate(): Observable<any>{
    return this._animate.asObservable();
}
```

Also, in `LoadService`, to update our `observable` value:

```
toggleAnimation(value: boolean){
   oldValue = this._animate.getValue();
   this._animate.next(!oldValue);
}
```

### Component

Now in our component, you can subscribe to it like this:

```
constructor(private service: LoadService) {
    this.service.animate.subscribe(state => {
        // do stuff
        console.log(state);
    })
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't `animate` have a return type of `Observable<any>` in order to be subscribed to?

Comment: This seems to work, it's odd that it did not work with `Subject` but it did with `BehaviorSubject`, I'll have to read the doc. Thank you !

Comment: our `get` function returns an `Observable<any>`. I have updated its return type to make it clear.

Comment: you haven't mentioned use of `Subject` in your code. But `Subject` emits it value only after that source Observable completes. Where `BehaviorSubject` emits its last available value upon subscription. see http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html

Answer (score 0):

Angular team discourage the usage of eventemitter in a service, since it's used as an abstraction around a Subject. You can create an observable with custom logic by using the new keywork, and by providing the logic of the emission, or you can use a Subject, which is an observable and an observer, think of it as the most similar implementation of the observer pattern.

```
loadServiceSubject : Subject<any> = new Subject();
loadService$ : Observable<any> = loadServiceSubject.asObservable();
// other code
```

Think of the subject as a proxy between the event emitter and the listeners, anytime you call the next function on the subject, the emitted value will be pushed to all the subscribers of the observable.

```
// in client code
// suppose the service is injected in the constructor
this.animationService.loadService$.subscribe( this.doStuffOnNextCallback );
```

The "event" emitter just need to call the next, error or complete function on the subject itself.

```
// producer code, supposing it's also injected
this.animationService.loadServiceSubject.next(true);
```